# How large would space warships be?

Tags: warfare, space-warfare, future

How large would space warships be? Resources are limited to that of the inner Hills cloud & inward. The main concern is fighting within the solar system. Earth is still the only habitable planet but there are colonies on most rocky planets & large moons. Fighting is between earth powers that control various colonies on various planets & moons. A few independent colonies exist but they are small & not that relevant. Orbital bombardment isn't relevant for complicated reasons. The available weapons are lasers, missiles, coil guns, Combustion light-gas guns & conventional guns. The most common power source is fission reactors. Most ships move by either burning hydrogen or various types of nuclear engine. The armour is restricted to metal & composites. There are no shields. The technology level is near future. Ships are built in orbit

What size would space warships be under these conditions?

Comment: How long is a piece of string? Without knowing the weapon and engine specs along with the engine efficiency, desired thrust, and Delta V budget as a bare minimum, we can't **begin** to answer this question.

Comment: It very strongly depends on what those warships are intended to do, doesn't it? And the question doesn't say what would be the kind of missions those ships are intended to fulfill. (Please note that with existing or immediately foreseeable technology we cannot, as in *absolutely* cannot, make a spacecraft which has anything remotely resembling the freedom of maneuver of a sea ship. The tyranny of the rocket equation is extremely harsh.)

Comment: @Ash i haven't gotten much of the way of anything done regarding this, the space less-than-half of this world isn't something i've thought that much about until now. As well as that that type of thing hasn't been something i ever planned to do in any way.

Comment: That really depends on the details of the technology available and how much realism you want.  It sounds like you're looking for something more on the hard realism side of the scale, so what I'll suggest is getting a copy of the game "*Children of a Dead Earth*" which is a space combat simulator focused on tech that is known to be physically possible to get an idea of what designs are possible for a given tonnage and go from there.  I wouldn't necessarily call it fun *per se* but it is interesting and thought provoking.

Comment: @AlexP Fighting other space warships. I don't have that much in the way of specifics for the space part of my world yet.

Comment: For your interest: [deviant art Biggest Spaceships](https://www.deviantart.com/dirkloechel/art/Size-Comparison-Science-Fiction-Spaceships-398790051).

Comment: VTO: I agree that it is wild guessing game in this case, and understand desire to know more details, however, more details not necessarly that much helpfull. Near future and chemical and fission engines give barely sufficient feel of whats's may be possible/going on there. Existing aswer, illustrates the way how the q can be answered, even if it a bit too timid and can be improved.

Answer (score 1):

There are too many parameters to give a firm answer, but let me hazard a guess:

**Small(ish)**

There is a saying that *there's no stealth in space.* Correct, but I also believe that the problem of making initial contact is under-appreciated by many who say it. Breaking contact is hard, but a previously undetected stealth ship on an unpowered trajectory can be hard to tell from a random little rock.

So whatever the size of your freighters, refinery ships, and stations, the warships might be relatively small and relatively expendable. *One* railgun or a handful of missiles, plus secondary armaments, engines, avionics, and a small crew capsule if they are manned.

Carriers are not an option -- if a carrier is being tracked, all fighters it launched would be tracked, too. So the warships cannot be *too* small, they need enough life support for independent, year-long missions. How small can you get that life support? Or are there fully robotic craft?

Comment: per carriers: fighters remain launched prior to detection and only return to carrier for replenishment, and not if enemies are around to track back to carrier. Sort of like the replenishment subs used by German subs during WW2.

Comment: @MarkRipley If the carrier is burning to change orbit/location it can be tracked, light-lag-late from anywhere in the solar system with good enough optics or radio telescopes.

Comment: Are these optics in locations where they can be detected and destroyed? knowing the precise course a ship is on after a planetary pass by burn is not a trivial problem unless you know precisely how deep in the gravity field it was during the burn. If you have ships close enough to attack after the burn, no problem, but if enough time passes that's a big volume of space it could be in. Many SF books cover trying to track stealthy ships in large volumes of space, even if you know where they were at one time. Space is big, and your target may have gone home before you can close and attack it.

Comment: @MarkRipley, my assumption is that any object which maneuvers or fires within sight of hostile sensors gets detected and stays detected, and so do the launched objects. "Within sight" depends on the sensors and target size. So a big carrier must stay farther out to remain undetected, and fighters need endurance -- keep the carrier beyond detection and their mission time goes up, requiring larger fighters and larger carriers, which must stay even farther out. The way to go **may** be relatively small, long-range attack craft.

Comment: Once a target is detected the course is **completely** predictable unless it maneuvers, maneuvering expends energy and that can be tracked. Big volumes to hide only counts prior to that initial contact.

Comment: @o.m. If both sides have perfect sensors everyone knows where every manmade object in space is all the time. After all they had to boost at some point to get to wherever they are now located, so you have detected and will never lose them again. One side or the other can just send kinetic strikes against any enemy object from unlimited range. In theory anyway.

Comment: @o.m. If your imperfect sensors only see an object while maneuvering, you can't track it perfectly over time, because you can't determine the >>exact<< course of anything, whether enemy ships or yourself. A degree off and a few million miles later. a target is somewhere inside a moving volume a hundred miles across. Now this volume passes through any gravity field. If you don't know >>exactly<< where the target is in that volume, the gravity field will curve the target's course in a way you can't calculate, so you only have a limited time to kill it before you don't know where it is anymore.

Comment: @MarkRipley  Re: "*... SF books cover trying to track stealthy ships in large volumes of space ... *", The "science" part of SF novels tends to be of be pretty poor quality 99% of the time so they're not valid as counterexamples.

Comment: @GrumpyYoungMan You are correct that SF books often don't use real science, but they often suggest tactics that may apply (such as using decoy drones, or maneuvering while behind a planet to avoid detection) which is why I mentioned them. Also, this is worldbuilding, so reality is whatever the OP decides it is and science may not apply here. I feel a lot of worldbuilding questions are looking for ideas rather than science, unless they add the science-based tag to their question.